List of values of a key in Qdrant
I have a collection named Docs in the qdrant database. There are multiple points in this collection. Each point has metadata including the title of the document. I want to extract a list of titles. I tried to do it but it returned none. How can I do it?
from qdrant_client import QdrantClient, models

client = QdrantClient(url="http://localhost:6333")

result = client.scroll(
    collection_name="Docs",
    scroll_filter=models.Filter(
        must=[
            models.FieldCondition(
                key="meta.title",
                match=models.MatchText(text='*')
            )
        ]
    )
)

result


If you need to fetch the title from all the points, you don't need to specify a filter at all.
You're getting no results because your filter condition is trying to literally match "*", not as a regex(Not supported).

As of Qdrant v1.9 there isn't yet a dedicated endpoint for getting this list of unique values efficiently.
However, there is this grouping endpoint which may solve what you are looking for:
https://qdrant.tech/documentation/concepts/search/#search-groups
To make it work for your use-case -since it requires a vector- you can use a zeroed vector, a group_size of 1, and a large limit
